# Converting a php based website to a mobile app

Tags: php

Is there a posibility that i can convert my php website to an mobile app or i should convert it into html then convert it to mobile app??

Comment: make it responsive.. through UI/UX for other devices. You can use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cant run php client side. You should just make it a responsive website

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple technologies. You will need to adjust your HTML/CSS to cater for how they work, but it is possible. I'd suggest looking at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is server-side language and that gives HTML page output after execution at server-side so that is not possible.
But You can use native browser of that os e.g. for **android webview**.And can load your page into it.
Another option is **PhoneGap** but it slow down application than Native.